# Replace string without deleting structure of html

Tags: javascript, string, text, replace, innertext

When i try to replace string 0,50 with javascript 'mydiv' has been deleted/moved

Example

```
<div id="para1"><div class="mydiv"></div>0,50</div>
```

When i try to replace 0,50 by 80 i do :

```
document.getElementById("para1").innerText = "80"
```

or with jQuery

```
$("#para1").text("80")
```

then the result is :

```
<div id="para1">80</div>
```

during the operation it delete `<div class="mydiv"></div>`

How can i do to keep structure of html and result like this :

```
<div id="para1"><div class="mydiv"></div>80</div>
```

Comment: are you tried  something like `+=`

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model): [`childNodes`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), [`Text`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Text), [`textContent`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).